# Kubernetes Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: kubernetes

I configured my config file and when I run :

```
kubectl get nodes
```

I have this error :

```
Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I tried all this command but it still change nothing :

```
kubectl config set-cluster ${KUBE_CONTEXT} --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true \
--server=${KUBE_CONTEXT} 
--insecure-skip-tls-verify=true 

kubectl proxy --address 0.0.0.0 --accept-hosts '.*'
```

Comment: Its your local env or Cloud? Are you using `kubeadm`, `minikube`, etc? What K8s version are you using?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The error indicates a possible certificate mismatch**.

Verify that the `$HOME/.kube/config` file contains a valid certificate, and regenerate a certificate if necessary.

Unset the KUBECONFIG environment variable using:

```
unset KUBECONFIG
```

Or set it to the default KUBECONFIG location:

```
export KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
```

**Another workaround is to overwrite the existing kubeconfig for the "admin" user**

```
mv  $HOME/.kube $HOME/.kube.bak
mkdir $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

Refer [Link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/troubleshooting-kubeadm/#tls-certificate-errors)